# Locking when returning a cache entry from a asynchronous request

Tags: c#, web-services, locking, async-await, memorycache

I wrote a method that should get some information from a web service. 
I wanna avoid extra calls to the service, so I'm trying to put the information in the MemoryCache [according to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21269170/locking-pattern-for-proper-use-of-net-memorycache).

The difference is that I don't have "SomeHeavyAndExpensiveCalculation" at client, but I delegate the work to web service. So I want to await the call.

As I understand with current implementation I could have multiple requests to the web server, because I cannot await the request inside the lock and that's why it's moved out of the lock.

Is there a better solution?

Thanks.

```
 private static readonly object CompanyInfoLock = new object(); 

 public async Task<CompanyDto> GetCompanyInfo()
                {
                    const string cacheKey = "_COMPANYINFO_";

                    CompanyDto companyInfo = MemoryCache.Default[cacheKey] as CompanyDto;
                    if (companyInfo != null) return companyInfo;

                    CompanyDto company = await _userManagementService.InvokeAsync(x => x.GetCompanyAsync(AppPrincipal.Current.CurrentCompanyId));

                    lock (CompanyInfoLock)
                    {
                        companyInfo = MemoryCache.Default[cacheKey] as CompanyDto;
                        if (companyInfo != null) return companyInfo;
                        MemoryCache.Default.Add(cacheKey, company, new CacheItemPolicy
                        {
                            SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0)
                        });
                    }

                    return company;
                }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31831860/async-threadsafe-get-from-memorycache

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a [`SemaphoreSlim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphoreslim(v=vs.110).aspx) so you can lock asynchronously and put the lock block before you make the call to the web service.

```
private static readonly SemaphoreSlim CompanyInfoLock = new SemaphoreSlim (1); 

public async Task<CompanyDto> GetCompanyInfo()
{
    const string cacheKey = "_COMPANYINFO_";
    CompanyDto companyInfo;

    companyInfo = MemoryCache.Default[cacheKey] as CompanyDto;
    if (companyInfo != null) return companyInfo;

    await CompanyInfoLock.WaitAsync();
    try
    {
        //Check a 2nd time inside the lock to see if the cache has the data.
        companyInfo = MemoryCache.Default[cacheKey] as CompanyDto;
        if (companyInfo != null) return companyInfo;

        companyInfo = await _userManagementService.InvokeAsync(x => x.GetCompanyAsync(AppPrincipal.Current.CurrentCompanyId));

        MemoryCache.Default.Add(cacheKey, companyInfo, new CacheItemPolicy
        {
            SlidingExpiration = new TimeSpan(2, 0, 0)
        });

        return companyInfo;
    }
    finally
    {
        CompanyInfoLock.Release();
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this technique is called double-check locking and it's actually not that thread safe, at least with ordinary lock. Don't know if it is better with SemaphoreSlim