# Static List multithreaded application

Tags: c#, multithreading, static, instance, object-reference

```
public class Helper
{
    private static List<TimeZoneMap> timeZoneList = null;


public static List<TimeZoneMap> GetTimeZoneList()
{
    if (timeZoneList == null)
    {
        timeZoneList = new List<TimeZoneMap>();
        timeZoneList.Add(new TimeZoneMap() { Id = "Dateline Standard Time", DisplayName = "(UTC-12:00) International Date Line West" });
        timeZoneList.Add(new TimeZoneMap() { Id = "UTC-11", DisplayName = "(UTC-11:00) Coordinated Universal Time-11" });
        timeZoneList.Add(new TimeZoneMap() { Id = "Aleutian Standard Time", DisplayName = "(UTC-10:00) Aleutian Islands" });
    }
}
```

The `timeZoneList` gets initialized inside an instance class (Helper) but it is static a list.

A static method add items to this list based on null check.

In a multi threaded environment, the `timeZoneList` does not have all the values and return nulls randomly. This occurs for only 2 to 3 random instance out of the 200.

What we are doing wrong here ?

1. Static List
2. Static Method
3. An Instance class initialization inside the static list ?
4. or calling the same static method from different instances of parent class. ?

This is not frequently happening and cannot guess when the issue occurs as well.

Thinking of making this list as static readonly collection. But still doubt that would make the list read only. What on the initial load we get only 5 instead of all !?

Comment: You method is not returning anything.  Add to end of code : return timeZoneList;

Comment: You could consider initializing the `timeZoneList` in a static constructor, which [is thread-safe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7095/is-the-c-sharp-static-constructor-thread-safe).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If multiple threads call `GetTimeZoneList()` at the same time while `timeZoneList` is null, you'll get a race condition. The fact that it is static is irrelevant here.

The reason for this is that, if, say, two threads enter the method at the same time while the list is null, they'll both enter the `if` at the same time. That is bad, because now you have concurrent writes to the `timeZoneList` field, concurrent modification to a non thread-safe collection, or both. Ultimately, your problem is that you're sharing mutable states between threads, and that is always bad.

There's also the other issue of using a mutable collection (`List<T>`) for something that might be shared between threads, which creates the risk that some part of the code modifies it afterwards, wreaking further havoc. I recommend using something like `ImmutableArray<T>` instead:

```
var builder = ImmutableArray.CreateBuilder<TimeZoneMap>();
builder.Add(new TimeZoneMap() {
    Id = "Dateline Standard Time",
    DisplayName = "(UTC-12:00) International Date Line West" 
});
builder.Add(new TimeZoneMap() {
    Id = "UTC-11",
    DisplayName = "(UTC-11:00) Coordinated Universal Time-11" 
});
builder.Add(new TimeZoneMap() { 
    Id = "Aleutian Standard Time", 
    DisplayName = "(UTC-10:00) Aleutian Islands" 
});}
return builder.ToImmutable();
```

Once the `ImmutableArray<T>` is constructed, it cannot be changed, preventing other problems. You can then choose to return `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` or `IReadOnlyList<T>` to hide that implementation detail.

Let's look at your options.

#### 1. Make it immutable

Initialisation of a static field is guaranteed to happen only once, so this is inherently thread safe:

```
private static readonly ImmutableArray<TimeZoneMap> timeZoneList 
    = CreateTimeZoneList();

private static ImmutableArray<TimeZoneMap> CreateTimeZoneList()
{
    // create, fill and return the list
}

public static IReadOnlyList<TimeZoneMap> GetTimeZoneList() 
    => timeZoneList;
```

It does have the issue of making the initialisation eager, which might not be what you want. To keep it lazy, read on.

#### 2. Lock it

Use the `lock` statement with an object to control access to the field:

```
private static ImmutableArray<TimeZoneMap> timeZoneList = null;
private static readonly object timeZoneLock = new object();

public static IReadOnlyList<TimeZoneMap> GetTimeZoneList()
{
    lock(timeZoneLock)
    {
        if (timeZoneList == null)
        {
            // etc.
        }
    }
    return timeZoneList;
}
```

That's fairly straightforward, but a bit verbose. Also, it looks like a singleton, and I don't like singletons. You could also do another null check outside of the lock to avoid locking it unnecessarily, but that's an optimisation. Up to you.

#### Use `Lazy<T>`

For me, this is the best approach: it's simpler, leaner, and more robust.

`Lazy<T>` is a class that, as its name implies, contains a value that is lazily initialised. By default, this object performs its initialisation in a thread safe manner (specifically, with the [`ExecutionAndPublication`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.lazythreadsafetymode) thread safety mode), so, you could do this:

```
private static readonly Lazy<ImmutableArray<TimeZoneMap>> timeZoneList 
    = new Lazy<ImmutableArray<TimeZoneMap>>(CreateTimeZoneList);

private static ImmutableArray<TimeZoneMap> CreateTimeZoneList()
{
    // ...
}

public static IReadOnlyList<TimeZoneMap> GetTimeZoneList() 
    => timeZoneList.Value;
```

The above eagerly creates the lazy object, specifying the method to use as its factory. The list is initially not created. The first time some gets the lazy's `Value` (by calling `GetTimeZoneList()`), it will then be properly initialised. Subsequent calls return the same list. If multiple thread do so at the same time, the factory method will still be called only once, and all threads then get the same exact list.

Comment: Excellent and thanks a ton for the detailed answer... Will go ahead with Lazy and will come back here if we come across the issue again.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `Lazy<List<TimeZoneMap>>` instead of `List<TimeZoneMap>`? It could itself take care of initialization.

Answer (score 1):

You need the singleton pattern here.

The objective is to allow multiple threads to enter if the first arriving thread is null, locking the object in the process. Subsequent arriving threads wait for the other thread. Since simultaneous locking is possible, an additional check is implemented for this purpose.

```
public class Helper
{
    private static List<TimeZoneMap> timeZoneList = null;
    private static readonly object lockObject = new object();

    public static List<TimeZoneMap> GetTimeZoneList()
    {
        // Double-check locking for optimization
        if (timeZoneList == null)
        {
            lock (lockObject)
            {
                if (timeZoneList == null)
                {
                    timeZoneList = new List<TimeZoneMap>
                    {
                        new TimeZoneMap { 
                          Id = "Dateline Standard Time",
                          DisplayName = "(UTC-12:00) International Date Line West" 
                        },
                        new TimeZoneMap { 
                          Id = "UTC-11", 
                          DisplayName = "(UTC-11:00) Coordinated Universal Time-11"
                        },
                        new TimeZoneMap { 
                          Id = "Aleutian Standard Time", 
                          DisplayName = "(UTC-10:00) Aleutian Islands"
                        }
                    };
                }
            }
        }

        return timeZoneList;
    }
}
```

**Edit: Correction for my response.**

I conducted further research on this topic. Certainly, as a result, I now prefer to use 'Lazy' or 'AsyncLazy'.

Comment: The easiest implementation of a singleton is to use `Lazy<T>` as suggested by @Alexanderpowolozki in his answer

Comment: Double-checked locking [is dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394898/double-checked-locking-in-net). If you are not an expert on memory barriers (aka acquire and release fences), forget about it.

Comment: It seems odd to me to create a list with thread-safety and then release the reference to calling code. Thread-safety goes poof!

Comment: @TheodorZoulias, enigmativity, thank you for your feedback. I conducted further research on this topic. Certainly, as a result, I now prefer to use 'Lazy' or 'AsyncLazy'.